# Zend Search Lucene And Persian Language !

Tags: zend-framework, utf-8, lucene, persian

i have the following code in my zf project :

```
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open(APPLICATION_PATH . '/cache/search_index');
        $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();

        $title = "سلام سینا xxx sad";



        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('title', $title));

        $index->addDocument($doc);
        $index->commit();

        $index->optimize();
        echo "Index contains " . $index->count() . " documents.\n\n";
        $results = $index->find('xxx');
        foreach ($results as $res) {


            var_dump($res->title);
        }
```

when var_dump performs  output ->
string(39) "Ø³ÛŒÙ†Ø§ Ø¬Ø§Ù† xxx sad"

when i user utf_decode
string(25) "س�?ا�? س�?�?ا xxx sad"

how can i decode that correctly ! :(?

i already used the solution in this  SOF  quesion -> [lucene encoding problem in zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834861/lucene-encoding-problem-in-zend-framework)

but not works and a notice error added about iconv  !

plz help :)

Comment: salam,man data ro az database miaram va ghabl az index kardanesh dorost neshun mide vali vaghti documentam ro index mikonam va y reshte  e farsi search mikonam natije ii nemibinam,idea ii darin?

Comment: @SamiraKhorshidi lotf kon finglish nanevis inja ... lotfan biain to gmail ... codeton ro bayad bebinam miandashti@gmail.com

Comment: mamnun,moshkel hal shod inam rahe hal :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834861/lucene-encoding-problem-in-zend-framework/5834910#5834910

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by this code:

```
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open(APPLICATION_PATH . '/cache/search_index');
    $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();

    $title = "سلام سینا xxx sad";



    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('title', $title,"UTF8"));

    $index->addDocument($doc);
    $index->commit();

    $index->optimize();
    echo "Index contains " . $index->count() . " documents.\n\n";



    var_dump($index->getDocument(9));

    echo "Search";
     $results = $index->find('سینا');
   foreach ($results as $res) {


        var_dump($res->title);
    }

    die(1);
```